# Using OpenMP to for optimizing BiLinear Interpolation

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp, hpc

I'm working on ARM, and I'm trying to optimize downsampling an image, I have used OpenCV cv::resize and its slow ~3ms for 1280*960 to 400*300, I'm trying to use OpenMP to accelerate it, however while putting the parallel for statement, the image has been distorted. I know that is related to private variables and shared data between the threads, but I can't find the problem.

```
void  resizeBilinearGray(uint8_t *pixels, uint8_t *temp, int w, int h, int w2, int h2) {

    int A, B, C, D, x, y, index, gray ;
    float x_ratio = ((float)(w-1))/w2 ;
    float y_ratio = ((float)(h-1))/h2 ;
    float x_diff, y_diff;
    int offset = 0 ;


#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0;i<h2;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<w2;j++) {
            x = (int)(x_ratio * j) ;
            y = (int)(y_ratio * i) ;
            x_diff = (x_ratio * j) - x ;
            y_diff = (y_ratio * i) - y ;
            index = y*w+x ;

            // range is 0 to 255 thus bitwise AND with 0xff
            A = pixels[index] & 0xff ;
            B = pixels[index+1] & 0xff ;
            C = pixels[index+w] & 0xff ;
            D = pixels[index+w+1] & 0xff ;

            // Y = A(1-w)(1-h) + B(w)(1-h) + C(h)(1-w) + Dwh
            gray = (int)(
                        A*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +  B*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                        C*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   +  D*(x_diff*y_diff)
                        ) ;

            temp[offset++] = gray ;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try replacing temp[offset++] with temp[i*w2 + j]?

Your offset has multiple problems.  For one it has a race condition.  But worse is that OpenMP is assigning very different i and j values to each thread so they are reading non adjacent parts of memory. That's why your image is distorted.

Besides OpenMP there are several other ways to speed up your code you could try.  I don't know ARM but on Intel you can get a big speed up with SSE.  Additionally, you could try fixed floating point.  I have found speed ups with both in bilinear interpolation.
fastcpp.blogspot.no/2011/06/bilinear-pixel-interpolation-using-sse.html

Comment: so you think i, k should be private variables? what about also the other nested loop ? 
After I try that, I'm gonna try ARM Neon

Comment: i and j are already private variables by virtue of being defined after the openmp pragma.  Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: If you want more information about loop nesting see this link.  But it's not going to fix your image distortion.  That's due to how you use offset.  You need to replace temp[offset++] with temp[i*w2 + j]

http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#ReductionClause

Comment: I'm just curious, why are you suggesting that he use SSE *over* OpenMP, which covers vectorisation on both Intel and Arm platforms? SSE + AVX are exactly what OpenMP uses to do its work!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the `offset` variable. Since many threads can work at the same time, you never know which thread will update offset first. This is why the resulting image is distorted.

A better strategy is to iterate on the resulting image pixels. For each resulting pixel, you find the coordinates of the source image pixels, perform the interpolation, and write the result. This way, you are sure each thread work on different pixels, and on the right pixel.